# php://input empty on Azure

Tags: php, json, angularjs, post, azure

I'm posting a complex JSON object to my Azure IIS running PHP 5.4 using AngularJS:

```
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "/php/mail.php",
    data: $scope.contactForm,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

My PHP script consist of these two lines:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
print_r($data);
```

When trying to read the POSTed data, all arrays (`$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, and `php://input`) are empty.
There are no redirects in place that would kill the `POST` data and echoing `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` returns `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.

Comment: Does it work on a server outside of Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Since your PHP is expecting JSON, you're Content-Type is incorrect.  Also, you'll need to stringify the data, so your AngularJS code would look like this:

```
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "/php/mail.php",
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.contactForm),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```